# Using Xcode 6.3' incremental builts without Swift 1.2

Tags: xcode, swift

Is it possible to use the new Xcode 6.3 version without having to implement Swift 1.2?

As we're building an app with a submission date before the end of march, Xcode 6.3 will probably not yet be in GM release to submit our app with Swift 1.2.

As the incremental builds make developing with Swift a lot better, it would be great to still use this new version of Xcode 6.3.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the incremental builds feature is actually a part of the [Swift 1.2](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=22) compiler updates as opposed to Xcode 6.3 itself.

Therefore you will not be able to use the Xcode 6.3 for development because of the significant language changes in Swift 1.2 whilst it is in Beta.